# Make nested object structure from flat structure and reverse?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, tree, flatten

I have a flat array. Like this:

```
const inputArray = [
  {
    path: '1',
    id: '1'
  },
  {
    path: '2',
    id: '2'
  },
  {
    path: '3',
    id: '3'
  },
  {
    path: '3.4',
    id: '4'
  },
  {
    path: '3.5',
    id: '5'
  },
  {
    path: '3.4.6',
    id: '6'
  },
  {
    path: '3.4.7',
    id: '7'
  },
  {
    path: '8',
    id: '8'
  },
]
```

Where `path` is unique path of the element by id. For example, `path: '3.5'` means that this object is child for object with `id: '3'`. And `path: '3.4.6'` is child for `path: '3.4'`.
I want collect them to nested structure. So result should be like this.

```
const result = [
  {
    path: '1',
    id: '1',
    children: []
  },
  {
    path: '2',
    id: '2',
    children: []
  },
  {
    path: '3',
    id: '3',
    children: [
      {
        path: '3.4',
        id: '4',
        children: [
           {
            path: '3.4.6',
            id: '6',
            children: []
          },
          {
            path: '3.4.7',
            id: '7',
            children: []
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '3.5',
        id: '5',
        children: []
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '8',
    id: '8',
    children: []
  },
]
```

And also i need a second algorithm to convert them back, from nested to flat structure. Can you give ad advice please?

UPDATE: Data is not sorted. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rr9vmq?file=index.js) is my try, but there is too much code and it fails in some cases. I feel that there should be better way to make this.

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried so far to accomplish this yourself?

Comment: Please share your attempt as a working snippet using `<>`

Comment: is the data sorted?

Comment: @Nina Scholz - no

Comment: I updated answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), [Array.findIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findindex), [Array.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) and [Array.shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

**Convert to Tree**

- Assuming that `input array` is **sorted** by path, otherwise, you will not sort `inputArray.sort((a,b) => a.path - b.path);`
- Reduce the array to form the tree
- Create an array of the hierarchy by splitting the path and creating a number array from it
- Create a function `addChildren` which will take 3 inputs

  - a -> Parent object (array) in which object will be inserted
  - c -> object that needs to be inserted
  - t -> array of hierarchy of the object which needs to be inserted
- Function takes the first value of `t` and if its last in hierarchy then
  it means that the `a` is the valid placeholder for the object. Hence, 
  push it there. In case there are remaining values then find the
  placeholder from the array by matching the `id`. Now, again call the
  function with `a` will become the `children` array of the **matched object**,
  `c` remains the same and `t` will be the remaining array of hierarchy.

```js
const inputArray = [{path:'1',id:'1'},{path:'2',id:'2'},{path:'3',id:'3'},{path:'3.4',id:'4'},{path:'3.5',id:'5'},{path:'3.4.6',id:'6'},{path:'3.4.7',id:'7'},{path:'8',id:'8'}];

const result = inputArray.reduce((a,c) => {
  let t = c.path.split(".").map(Number);
  addChildren(a,c,t);
  return a;
}, []);

function addChildren(a, c, t) {
  let val = t.shift();
  if(!t.length) {
    a.push({...c, children : []});
  } else {
    var i = a.findIndex(({id}) => Number(id) === val);
    addChildren(a[i].children, c, t);
  }
}
console.log(result);
```

**Flatten Tree**

- Create a function that take 2 inputs

  - a -> Input array (Array of children)
  - r -> Resulting array
- Function iterates over the input array and pushes the objects in the 
  result array and check for any children, if yes, then call the function
  for children as well

```js
var inputArray = [{path:'1',id:'1',children:[]},{path:'2',id:'2',children:[]},{path:'3',id:'3',children:[{path:'3.4',id:'4',children:[{path:'3.4.6',id:'6',children:[]},{path:'3.4.7',id:'7',children:[]},]},{path:'3.5',id:'5',children:[]},]},{path:'8',id:'8',children:[]},];

function flattenArray(a, r) {
  a.forEach(({children, ...rest}) => {
    r.push(rest);
    if(children) flattenArray(children, r)
  });
}
var result = [];
flattenArray(inputArray, result);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want more versability, you can create tree-structure from the input and then do whatever you want with it (i.e. output in some format you want, add methods for finding some item etc.)

```js
const inputArray = [
    {
        path: '1',
        id: '1'
    },
    {
        path: '2',
        id: '2'
    },
    {
        path: '3',
        id: '3'
    },
    {
        path: '3.4',
        id: '4'
    },
    {
        path: '3.5',
        id: '5'
    },
    {
        path: '3.4.6',
        id: '6'
    },
    {
        path: '3.4.7',
        id: '7'
    },
    {
        path: '8',
        id: '8'
    },
];

class Tree {
    constructor() {
        this.root = {};
    }

    addNewNode(path, node) {
        const pathArr = path.split('.');
        let currentNode = this.root;
        pathArr.forEach(item => {
            if (!currentNode[item]) {
                currentNode[item] = {};
            }
            currentNode = currentNode[item];
        });
        currentNode.data = node;
    }
}

const tree = new Tree();
inputArray.forEach(val => tree.addNewNode(val.path, val));
console.log(tree);
```

The output is the output of a tree, not the exact output you included - it is up to you, how you proceed with it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an object as helper structure for unsorted data and build a tree.

For getting a flat array, you could iterate the tree and concat the flat children with a recursive function.

```js
function getTree(array) {
    var o = {};
    array.forEach(({ id, path }) => {
        var parents = path.split('.'),
            parent = parents[parents.length - 2];

        Object.assign(o[id] = o[id] || {}, { id, path });
        o[parent] = o[parent] || {};
        o[parent].children = o[parent].children || [];
        o[parent].children.push(o[id]);
    });
    return o.undefined.children;
}

function getFlat(array = []) {
    return array.reduce((r, { id, path, children }) =>
        r.concat({ id, path }, getFlat(children)), []);
}

var input = [{ path: '1', id: '1' }, { path: '2', id: '2' }, { path: '3', id: '3' }, { path: '3.4', id: '4' }, { path: '3.5', id: '5' }, { path: '3.4.6', id: '6' }, { path: '3.4.7', id: '7' }, { path: '8', id: '8' }],
    tree = getTree(input),
    flat = getFlat(tree);

console.log(tree);
console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

A solution without keeping `path`.

```js
function getTree(array) {
    var o = {};
    array.forEach(({ id, path }) => {
        var parents = path.split('.'),
            parent = parents[parents.length - 2];

        Object.assign(o[id] = o[id] || {}, { id });
        o[parent] = o[parent] || {};
        o[parent].children = o[parent].children || [];
        o[parent].children.push(o[id]);
    });
    return o.undefined.children;
}

function getFlat(array = [], path = []) {
    return array.reduce((r, { id, children }) => {
        var p = path.concat(id);
        return r.concat({ id, path: p.join('.') }, getFlat(children, p));
    }, []);
}

var input = [{ path: '1', id: '1' }, { path: '2', id: '2' }, { path: '3', id: '3' }, { path: '3.4', id: '4' }, { path: '3.5', id: '5' }, { path: '3.4.6', id: '6' }, { path: '3.4.7', id: '7' }, { path: '8', id: '8' }],
    tree = getTree(input),
    flat = getFlat(tree);

console.log(tree);
console.log(flat);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Cool, but this will not work properly in [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gozzxs?file=index.js) case

Comment: Sorry, i was not clear enough. I updated link. I used same id's twice. In my case it is possible. And it rewrite property in `{ "id": "4", "path": "3.4", "children":[]`

Comment: you try to create a circular reference, which leads to infinite nested objects. this object needs to be use with another object to keep the reference and stop recursive call for displaying the values.